# sklearn partial fit of CountVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Does `CountVectorizer` support partial fit?

I would like to train the `CountVectorizer` using different batches of data.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not support partial fit.

But you can write a simple method to accomplish your goal:

```
def partial_fit(self , data):
    if(hasattr(vectorizer , 'vocabulary_')):
        vocab = self.vocabulary_
    else:
        vocab = {}
    self.fit(data)
    vocab = list(set(vocab.keys()).union(set(self.vocabulary_ )))
    self.vocabulary_ = {vocab[i] : i for i in range(len(vocab))}

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
CountVectorizer.partial_fit = partial_fit

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=l)
vectorizer.fit(df[15].values[0:100])
vectorizer.partial_fit(df[15].values[100:200])
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation by **sajiad** is correct and I'm grateful to them for sharing their solution. It could be made more flexible by amending the call to `hasattr()` to reference `self` instead of `vectorizer`.

I've implemented this with a short reproducible example below illustrating the role of `partial_fit()` compared to `fit()`:

```
def partial_fit(self , data):
    if(hasattr(self , 'vocabulary_')):
        vocab = self.vocabulary_
    else:
        vocab = {}
    self.fit(data)
    vocab = list(set(vocab.keys()).union(set(self.vocabulary_ )))
    self.vocabulary_ = {vocab[i] : i for i in range(len(vocab))}

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
CountVectorizer.partial_fit = partial_fit

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

corpus = ['The quick brown fox',
'jumps over the lazy dog']

# Without partial fit
for i in corpus:
    vectorizer.fit([i])

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

> ['dog', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'over', 'the']

```
# With partial fit
for i in corpus:
    vectorizer.partial_fit([i])

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

> ['over', 'fox', 'lazy', 'quick', 'the', 'jumps', 'dog', 'brown']